# Creating new AppDomain calling method in same class as the AppDomain in made

Tags: c#, appdomain

I want to start below potentially long running thread in it's own AppDomain to prevent the webserver from aborting it during recycling. It compiles fine, however during runtime I get this cryptic error

> Type is not resolved for member 'MyCore.MyWebService,MyCore,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

How do I find out what member is not resolved?

Are there any better ways running a long standing thread in a MVC business service layer, that does not get aborted by the server recycling mechanism?

Here is the code:

```
namespace MyCore
{
  [Serializable]
  public class MyWebService : IMyWebService
  {
      AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain");
      Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MVCThread";
      domain.SetData("lDatabaseID", lDatabaseID);

      domain.DoCallBack(() =>
      {
        long lID = Convert.ToInt64(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("lDatabaseID"));
        Thread thread = new Thread(
        (() =>
        {
             PopulateTables(lID );
        }));
        thread.Name = "DomThread";
        thread.Start();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that starting a thread in a new AppDomain would prevent IIS from recycling your ASP.NET application and the entire w3p associated process? You can simply forget about having reliable long running tasks on background threads in IIS. That's not what a web server is designed for.

Comment: You are right, I poked around and might have found a solution using Hangfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after having mucked with Hangfire, I finally got it to work in .Net 4.0 and MVC 3. Had to install Common.Logging.Core 2.2.0, since the NuGet installed the wrong version (3.3.0)

In my Initial controller I added the following

```
namespace Core.Controllers
{
...
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    app.UseHangfire(config =>
    {
        config.UseSqlServerStorage(ConnectionString.GetTVConnectionString());
        config.UseServer();
    });
  }
...
}
```

ConnectionString.GetTVConnectionString() gets the connection string from the config file.

Up top I added the following

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Core.Controllers.BaseController))]
```

In the code that starts the background thread I added the following, passing in a long instead of the class and having the job load the POCO class from the db.

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => PopulateTables(lDatabaseID, JobCancellationToken.Null));
```

The Enqueue() function returns a job id, that later can be used to cancel the job if needed, through the BackgroundJob.Delete(jobid) function.

In the job method I then have this

```
while (idxMin < max)
{
    try
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ....
    }
    catch (JobAbortedException jobEx)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

It's important to use dependency injection, so my class had a parameter less constructor added that re-reads the connection string rather than have it passed in.

```
public MyWebService ()
        : this(ConnectionString.GetTVConnectionString())
{
}

public MyWebService (string sConnStr)
{
    msConnStr = sConnStr;
}
```

After that it seems to run pretty well. A number of tables are added to the database specified in the connection string. So far it seems like the jobs survive recycling on the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

IIS is heavily optimised to respond very quickly to hundreds of small simultaneous requests and just isn't the right tool for what you're attempting.  You can try to work around that but in the long term you'll be better off building a tool that is designed for long-running tasks.  You've then got a pre-packaged solution the next time this problem arises.

The basic idea is to create an external application that does your background processing with some way to pass tasks to it and get results back.  I like using the database to communicate as most web applications that need baground processing already use a database.  Add a 'tasks' table with {status, startedDateTime, finishedDateTime, parameters, etc}, then write an external application that will periodically look for a new task, complete it and update the database.  Your web site can poll the database for status or your application could make an AJAX call to notify the web site when a job has completed (a small iframe in the web site header that shows waiting / completed tasks can be useful if someone will be waiting for the job to complete and is easy to do).

EDIT: Before you do the above review HangFire (which works inside IIS, as a Windows Service or as a console app).  Same principles, but a pre-packaged solution.  Note that I haven't implemented this yet but it looks good.

Although it's a bit of work to set up, handing this task off to a Windows Service is a good approach if you might have multiple tasks and need them responded to quickly.  There are a lot of tutorials on the web that will help you create a Windows Service, such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106742/Creating-a-simple-Windows-Service but you'll have to build a simple task executor on top of that so if that's the way you want to go I'd look for a pre-built task engine (I couldn't find one quickly but I'm probably using the wrong search phrase).

But that's overkill if turn-around time isn't important and a better approach for you might be to create a small console application that will be started every five minutes by task scheduler.  It would connect to the database, execute any waiting tasks then shut down again.  This is easier to debug and install than a Windows service and achieves the same goal of moving the task execution out of IIS.

Remember that you still have to detect and handle Windows shutdown so that you don't get half-finished orphaned jobs - at the very least just tag that task as aborted and exit cleanly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I poked some more around and might have found the solution in Hangfire.

Comment: Thanks for the mention.  HangFire looks excellent for a project I'm working on now.  I think I'll keep my processing in a Windows Service but replace my half-built task system with HangFire.  Why not answer your own question?  I think HangFire is the right answer here.

Comment: Well, I have been trying all day to get Hangfire to play, I just cannot seem to get it to work, maybe there is a mismatch between the libraries I use and some of the requirements Hangfire seem to have. It uses Owin and WebHost. If I use NuGet to install Hangfire, I cannot seem to start my web app any longer. I'm also using .Net 4.0 and MVC 3.0 (at the moment I don't have the time to risk upgrading, since it always seem to be a time consuming process). This is the reason why I hesitate putting hangfire in as the answer. But you might have better luck than me.